# What would be a good "CMS" for me to use?

Tags: version-control, pdf, content-management-system, multilingual

I'm looking for some sort of CMS system to implement here in terms of "documentation" system.
Now, I'm not to sure about which system(s) would suit my needs best, so I thought I'd come here and type up my requirements so you could help me in narrowing down all the different options.
One important note to make is that I'm not looking at a system where I can store certain documents (word, pdf, whatever). Rather at a system where I can type the "documentation"-text in some sort of post (like a blog).

**Requirements:**
- Multilanguage support
- Tagging
- Decent search support (tags, groupings, categories)
- Version-control of posts/articles
- Possibility of exporting post(s) to a pdf file
- Support for multi-user (usergroup X can only see those posts, usergroup Y can see others, etc...)

I know, these are some strange requirements if they're all combined, and I reckon most of you would perhaps say that I'd have to develop something like this inhouse rather then finding a descent working product out there (open source if possible).
None the less, I thought I'd at least ask the opinion of y'all.

Regards,
Tim

Comment: Who is this for?  End users or developers?

Comment: If the purpose is to store documentation, wouldn't a wiki system fit better than a CMS?

Comment: @nuqqsa:  That's what I was thinking too.  :)

Comment: It's for end-users and maybe also for our developers (not sure about that part yet), but I will have a look around the web for some wiki tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You definitely need a Wiki. It doesn't matter if it's for developers or end-users, it meets all of your criteria.

Things like exporting to pdf might not come standard but it could be accomplished using a plugin.  I've used a few wikis in the past, mediaWiki, OpenWiki, Twiki and currently Screwturn wiki.  They all have their pros and cons, they all work on different systems (apache, iis, sqlbased, file based, etc..).

I would suggest you doing a little comparison investigation to decide which wiki you like best.  Whichever you pick will meet your needs.

Here is a comparison [chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_software), hope this helps

good luck

-D

Comment: Sure thing, here is another WIKI comparison tool http://www.wikimatrix.org/ . It's a bit more overwhelming but it might help you narrow down your decision.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export to PDF with hi-resolution images maybe following answer will be help:
[CMS and store hi-resolution images in generated pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24227632/cms-and-store-hi-resolution-images-in-generated-pdf/24227633#24227633)