# CMS and store hi-resolution images in generated pdf

Tags: pdf, content-management-system, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, tiki-wiki

I'm looking for good CMS for publishing software manuals.

**Requirements:**

- publish manual pages as web pages with thumbnails and shows full resolution after click on image,
- exporting manual pages to a pdf file **with full resolution images instead to thumbnails**.

I found IMHO best wiki system named *Tiki Wiki* (https://info.tiki.org/) but when I export to pdf then I gets low resolution thumbnail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem by very simple *Tiki Wiki* code modification:

Modify *lib/wiki-plugins/wikiplugin_img.php* to force using full image resolution instead to thumbnail in print page mode (inserted code 1) and rescale images in generated HTML by 0.5 factor (inserted code 2):

```
[...]

function wikiplugin_img( $data, $params )
{
    [...]

    $imgdata = array_merge($imgdata, $params);

    // inserted code 1 (~410 line)
    if ($GLOBALS['section_class']=="tiki_wiki_page print"){
        $imgdata['thumb'] = '';
    }
    // end of inserted code 1

    //function calls
    if ( !empty($imgdata['default']) || !empty($imgdata['mandatory'])) {

    [...]

    $fwidth = '';
    $fheight = '';
    if (isset(TikiLib::lib('parser')->option['indexing']) && TikiLib::lib('parser')->option['indexing']) {
        $fwidth = 1;
        $fheight = 1;
    } else {

        // inserted code 2 (~410 line)
        if ($GLOBALS['section_class']=="tiki_wiki_page print"){
            $fwidth = $imageObj->get_width() / 2;
            $fheight = $imageObj->get_height() / 2;
        } else {
            $fwidth = $imageObj->get_width();
            $fheight = $imageObj->get_height();
        }
        // end of inserted code 2 (~638 line)

     }

[...]
```

Now, after printing to pdf by **wkhtmltopdf** we gets pdf with small but full resolution images.

Additional modifies:

- Adds following lines to *cms/cssmenus.css* (or other css included in print mode) for increase bottom margin of image caption:

  ```
  div.thumbcaption {
      margin-bottom: 5mm;
  }
  ```
- Removes lines from 171 to ~175 in *templates/tiki-show_content.tpl* for remove the "The original document is available at" foot.